# download com requests e open python

Tags: python, python-3.x

O código seguinte faz parte de um loop que irá baixar vários arquivos
e salvar em seus respectivos diretórios.

Estou tentando baixar o arquivo da "url" e quero salvar em um diretório de escolha. O problema é que o arquivo não possui um padrão de nomes, é gerado de forma aleatória. Cada url possui seu arquivo com um nome não padronizado.

Minha dúvida seria como "pegar" o nome do arquivo para setar em `open('C:/teste/NOME_DO_ARQUIVO.zip'...`, já que é necessário o nome do arquivo para poder baixar e salvar.

```
url= "http://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmDownloadDocumento.aspx?CodigoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=98925" 
zip = requests.get(url, verify = False) 
with open('C:/teste/NOME_DO_ARQUIVO.zip', 'wb') as teste:
     teste.write(zip.content)
```

Comment: Saulo, bom dia! Você quer setar um nome arbitrariamente ou você quer que o nome seja o que vem por "padrão" no arquivo?

Comment: por padrão, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importando os pacotes necessários, observe que coloquei o warnings pois acusa um erro de ssl

```
import requests
import zipfile
import io
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Url do arquivo

```
url = 'http://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmDownloadDocumento.aspx?CodigoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=98925'
```

Requisição do arquivo

```
response = requests.get(url, verify = False, stream = True)
```

Criando o arquivo zip

```
file = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
```

Extraindo o arquivo(note que o path é o caminho onde você vai descompactar o arquivo, neste caso vai descompactar no diretório do script na pasta zips)

```
path = './zips'
file.extractall(path)
```

---

Código

```
import requests
import zipfile
import io
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

url = 'http://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmDownloadDocumento.aspx?CodigoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=98925'

response = requests.get(url, verify = False, stream = True)

file = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
path = './zips'
file.extractall(path)
```

---

**Update**

Para salvar sem extrair

```
import requests
import zipfile
import io
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

url = 'http://www.rad.cvm.gov.br/ENETCONSULTA/frmDownloadDocumento.aspx?CodigoInstituicao=1&NumeroSequencialDocumento=98925'

response = requests.get(url, verify = False, stream = True)

file = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))

name = ''.join(a for a in file.namelist() if a.endswith('itr'))[1:-4]
with open(f'{name}.zip', 'wb') as f:
    for a in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
        f.write(a)
```

Comment: obrigado lmonferrari, vou adaptar no codigo, abraço

Comment: Por nada Saulo, grande abraço!

Comment: lmonferrari o código foi bem útil, mas surgiu a dúvida de baixar sem descompactar, é possivel? agradeço

Comment: Fala Saulo, boa tarde! Adicionei um update a resposta com algumas modificações. Abraço!

Comment: perfeito @lmonferrari funcionou, eu fui além, acabei buscando o nome do arquivo no "headers" da pagina, segue minha resposta em baixo.

Answer (score 1):

obrigado mais uma vez @lmonferrari
A solução:

```
a = re.findall(r'filename=(.*)', zip.headers['content-disposition']): 
arq = "".join(a)
with open('C:/teste/' + arq, 'wb') as teste:
     teste.write(zip.content)
```

busca dentro o headers o nome do arquivo

```
a = re.findall(r'filename=(.*)', zipheaders['content-disposition']):
```

Converter o nome do arquivo de list para string:

```
arq = "".join(a)
```

Salva no diretório acrescentando o nome do arquivo

```
with open('C:/teste/' + arq, 'wb') as teste:
     teste.write(zip.content)
```